# certbot - Incomplete or failed recovery for /var/lib/letsencrypt/temp_checkpoint

Tags: lets-encrypt, certbot

If you have immutable nginx conf files, you will get the following error when running certbot:

## certbot

Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log
Unable to recover files from /var/lib/letsencrypt/temp_checkpoint
Incomplete or failed recovery for /var/lib/letsencrypt/temp_checkpoint
Unable to revert temporary config

Answer (score 4):

This is caused by files in the /var/lib/letsencrypt/temp_checkpoint getting out of sync. No big deal, just delete the temp files.

delete all file in the /var/lib/letsencrypt/temp_checkpoint directory

## rm /var/lib/letsencrypt/temp_checkpoint/*